# Ogre Assertion failed causing rviz to crash

Tags: ros, rviz, ogre, ros-groovy, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I try to run the demo from moveit from the sources (as it is not working from packing answers.ros.org/question/63227/issue-with-moveit-tutorials/)

But whenever I try to launch a launch file, it is not working : I get the following error :

```
rviz: /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreSceneManager.cpp :807 : virtual Ogre::SceneNode* Ogre::SceneManager::createSceneNode():  the assertion « mSceneNodes.find(sn->getName()) == mSceneNodes.end() » has failed.
```

It is driving me crazy! I made a fresh install on a VM and it is working perfectly!!

So I really don't know what's wrong with my system! I have the following configuration :

- Intel Core i7­3720QM
- Nvidia Quadro NVS 5200M GDDR5 1Go
- RAM 8Go DDR3 (2X4Go) 1600MHz

I think it might be related to my graphic card driver but I'm not really sure about it.

Thanks

Ben

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63584/ogre-assertion-failed-causing-rviz-to-crash/) by [BenjaminV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4952/benjaminv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This doesn't look like a driver related problem, I would guess something in MoveIt is causing this.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0